# Mercurial: how to abort 'graft' state?

Tags: mercurial

When a `hg graft` fails, it leaves behind `.hg/graftstate` which signals the graft-command that a graft is in process and can be continued. Except of deleting `.hg/graftstate`, is there a cleaner way to *abort* the grafting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want `hg update --clean .` The earlier answer was missing the "." to indicate where to update to.

Answer (score 3):

" hg update --clean " should do.

Comment: Didn't worked.  Removing the .hg/graftstate solved the issue.

Comment: This answer is missing `.` after `--clean`. Without `.` the command will update to the latest revision (`tip`) — but current revision before `hg graft` wasn't necessarily the `tip`. Please update or remove the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have anything important to push, then execute the following.

```
hg strip "roots(outgoing())"
```

Comment: "hg update --clean ." didn't work for me. This solution did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just delete the .hg/graftstate file

Comment: Might not be the best idea, but this worked while hg update --clean did not!